# Show $z e^{\lambda-z}-1$ has only one real root in the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

$z e^{\lambda-z}-1$ has only one real root in the unit disk for all  real $\lambda >1$

Usin calculus, I showed there is a root, but I can't see how I can use Rouche's theorem. I tried dividing and adding the different parts but it gets me nowhere. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: $$ze^{\lambda - z} - 1 = 0 \iff ze^{\lambda} - e^z = 0$$

Comment: I took it into consideration, but $e^z$ doesn't seem to have any zeros.

Comment: Right. But that's the term with smaller modulus on the unit circle.

Comment: So you mean I looked at it from a wrong perspective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(z)=ze^\lambda-e^z$, which, as the hint by Daniel Fischer notes, has the same zeros as your function. Let $g(z)=ze^\lambda$. Then $$|f(z)-g(z)|=e^z<|e^{\lambda-z}|+|e^\lambda|=|f(z)|+|g(z)|$$ holds on the boundary of the unit circle. Therefore $f(z)$, your function, and $g(z)$ all have the same number of complex zeroes inside the unit circle. $ze^\lambda$ very clearly has only one zero in this region.

Since you've proven there is at least one *real* root inside the unit circle, it follows that there is exactly one, since every real root is a complex root.